# Liquibase Remove identity from colunm

Tags: oracle, yaml, liquibase

I want to execute te command below in Liquibase using yaml language in a oracle database, how can I do that ?

```
alter table MYTABLE modify MYCOLUNM drop identity;
```

I tried some like that ( without success )

```
databaseChangeLog:
  - changeSet:
      ...
      changes:   
        -  modifyDataType:   
            columnName: MYCOLUNM  
            newDataType: number(9)
            autoIncrement: false 
            tableName: MYTABLE
```

There isn't error and the autoIncrement persists.
The result is:

**Liquibase command 'update' was executed successfully.**

Answer (score 1):

We don't have a change type for dropping an identity. The modifyDataType change doesn't try to modify whether it's an autoincrement or not, it focuses on the data type itself.

I created a bug for this issue here if you'd like to follow it: https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/issues/3180

The solution for now is just to specify the SQL that you want directly.

```
databaseChangeLog:
  - changeSet:
      ...
      changes:   
        -  sql:    
            sql: alter table MYTABLE modify MYCOLUNM drop identity;
```